# Header in every page SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, header, repeat

I have created 2 test reports.
The first report I just followed the wizard and created list through the wizard
the 2nd report I created a Table from Toolbox.

Everything looks fine, except the first one's header repeats on every page
while the 2nd is not.

I changed the property of the "Repeat header on each page" but still header is not repeated.

Anyone know why, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

1- add a row outside group - above

[image]

2- In Row Groups and Column Groups go to Advanced Mode

[image]

3- Select the Static on the top

[image]

4- F4 to go to the properties and change RepeatOnNewPage = True

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you click on *Insert -> Add Header* the header appears. Everything you write in this top section now will be repeated on every page. Maybe you dont have an page break. You can test it, when you insert a rectangle click on the rectangle properties under *General -> Add a page break after*. Now you have a page break and the header should be on the first and the second page.

Comment: what i want is a table header, not page header

Comment: There is not such a thing like a table header. You can add a textbox on the top of your tablix and use it as header. If you want to repeat the column header of the tablix under _Tablix properties -> General_ you can check the _Repeat header columns on each page_ and _Keep visible while scrolling_